# I'm getting an error in the authentication process in java mail API

Tags: java

Here's my java mail API code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.RecipientType;
import javax.activation.*;

import hostel.BabyAuthenticator;

class BabyAuthenticator extends Authenticator
{
   @Override
   protected PasswordAuthentication

   getPasswordAuthentication() 
   {
     PasswordAuthentication pa = new 
     PasswordAuthentication("my email-id","password of my account"); 

     return pa;
   }
}
```

I have tried 2-3 different email ids as sender's id ..but error still occurs.

```
  public class SendMail {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      try 
      {
        Properties p = new Properties();

        p.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.gmail.com");
        p.put("mail.smtp.port","587");
        p.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
        p.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
        p.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");

        BabyAuthenticator auth = new BabyAuthenticator();
        Session session = Session.getInstance(p,auth);

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("sender's email id"));

        InternetAddress receiver1 = new InternetAddress("receiver's email id");
        InternetAddress[] rcvrs = {receiver1};

        // specify the the type of Recipients
        message.addRecipients(RecipientType.TO,rcvrs);

        // provide the subject of email
        message.setSubject("First mail");

        // create object of MimeBodyPart to denote the body parts of mail 
        MimeBodyPart part1 = new MimeBodyPart();

        // associate some text to the body part 
        part1.setContent("<i style='color : blue'>"+ "This is my first mail"+" 
            </i>","text/html");

        MimeMultipart allParts = new MimeMultipart();

        allParts.addBodyPart(part1);
        message.setContent(allParts);
        Transport.send(message);

        // show message on console
        System.out.println("Mail has been sent to the mail server...");  
      } 
      catch (Exception e) 
      {
       System.out.println("Some error has occured, and error is "+e);
      }
  }
}
```

And here's the output of code:

> Some error has occured, and error is
>   javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and
>   Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 
>   https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials i72sm13717325pfj.147
>   - gsmtp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced this problem and has resolved the issue by:

- Allowing less secure app to access your google account [Learn more](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255)
- Switched to network provider, yes this is true, I tried with 3 network providers and send/receive mail works with 2 but not with other one, so I'm suggesting you to try switching the network provider also.